# Unable to Establish Connectivity from Kubernetes Cluster KB (VPC B) to RDS in Kubernetes Cluster KA (VPC A) in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

**Background**

- I have two Kubernetes clusters (KA and KB) in AWS EKS, both in the eu-west-2 region.
- Each cluster has its own VPC (VPC A for KA and VPC B for KB), with three public and three private subnets.
- RDS is deployed in VPC A (KA cluster) in one of the private subnets.

**Issue:**
facing difficulties establishing a connection from a pod running in Kubernetes Cluster KB (VPC B) to the RDS instance in Kubernetes Cluster KA (VPC A).

**Configuration details**

- VPC A details: CIDR => 192.168.0.0/16, 3 public subnets, 3 private subnets.
- VPC B details: CIDR => 192.168.0.0/16, 3 public subnets, 3 private subnets
- RDS instance details => it is deployed in VPC A (KA cluster).
- Relevant security group and route table configurations => I assigned security rule on RDS instance to allow all traffic from anywhere.

I tried to create a VPC peer-to-peer connection between two VPCs, but it was not working due to overlapping CIDR.